# Error ExecuteNonQuery:Connection property has not been initialized, when i click the insert button

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I've been trying to add data from Visual Studio to SQL server using c# language but it shows an error when I press the add button. The connection class is given below:

```
class Globalconnection
{
    public static SqlConnection cn;
    public static string strServer = "";
    public static string strDatabase = "";
    public static string strUID = "";
    public static string strPWD = "";

    public static void SetupConnection()
    {
        cn = new SqlConnection("Server=" + strServer + "; Database=" + strDatabase + "; UID=" + strUID + ";PWD=" + strPWD);
        cn.Open();
    }
}
```

In this class most of the SQL commands are given for inserting data into SQL.

```
class DACLASS
{
    public static string strUID = "";
    public static string strPWD = "";
    public static string strNPWD = "";
    public static DataTable AccessData()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Users where Username='" + strUID + "' and Password='" + strPWD + "'", Globalconnection.cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "USERS");
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }

    public static void addStatue(string ID, string Name)
    {
        string strAddStatue = "Insert into Statues  VALUES (@ID, @Name)";

        SqlCommand cmdAddStatue = new SqlCommand(strAddStatue, Globalconnection.cn);

        cmdAddStatue.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
        cmdAddStatue.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
        cmdAddStatue.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    }
}
```

The following command is from the from "ADD" button.

```
private void txtADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (txtID.Text == "" || txtName.Text == "" || txtSize.Text == "" || txtTCP.Text == "" || txtMP.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ID, Name, Size, Total Cost Price and Marked Price are Mandatory", "Handicrafts");
        }
        else
        {
            DACLASS.addStatue(txtID.Text, txtName.Text);
            MessageBox.Show("Statue Added", "Handicraft");
            btnClear_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Handicrafts");
        btnClear_Click(sender, e);
    }
}
```

When I put null values the Messagebox is displayed but when I insert the correct values I get this error

> ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized

Answer (score 3):

You need to open the `SqlConnection` before calling `ExecuteNonQuery` method from an instance of `SqlCommand`. After calling `ExecuteNonQuery`, the `SqlConnection` must be closed. I would suggest changing `Globalconnection` as below

```
class Globalconnection
{
    public static string strServer = "";
    public static string strDatabase = "";
    public static string strUID = "";
    public static string strPWD = "";
    public static SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Server=" + strServer + "; Database=" + strDatabase + "; UID=" + strUID + ";PWD=" + strPWD);
}
```

then use [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) inside `addStatue` method to make sure the `SqlConnection` is closed after `cmdAddStatue` is executed.

```
public static void addStatue(string ID, string Name)
{
    string strAddStatue = "Insert into Statues  VALUES (@ID, @Name)";

    using (var connection1 = Globalconnection.cn)
    {
        using (var cmdAddStatue = new SqlCommand(strAddStatue, connection1))
        {
            cmdAddStatue.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
            cmdAddStatue.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);

            connection1.Open();
            cmdAddStatue.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to add `connection1.Open();`

Comment: +1 for `using` statements.  The correct way to deal with ADO.Net.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your constructor, or in desperation to the txtADD_Click() method

```
 Globalconnection.SetupConnection();
```

You have done all the work to explain to the computer how to open the connection, you are just never actually telling it to DO it :)

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

It does seem like you never actually ran the setup connection method in the GlobalConnection class. maybe you'd be better implementing the singleton pattern around your sql connection.